# What don't I get about babel with istanbul?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs, istanbul

I'm trying to add code coverage to an existing library that transpiles from ES2015. I seem to be doing everything right. My makefile reads

```
test: .FORCE
    export NODE_ENV=test
    babel *.js --out-dir lib
    nyc mocha
```

And my babelrc reads

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "env": {
    "test": { "plugins": ["istanbul"] }
  }
}
```

while my package.json includes

```
"nyc": {
  "include": [
    "**/*.js"
  ],
  "require": [
    "babel-register"
  ],
  "sourceMap": false,
  "instrument": false
}
```

And yet, after my tests run, the output simply reads:

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

I've tried what feels like every combination of `babel-node`, `babel-istanbul`, and `nyc`, with various include directives, and I've never gotten it to so much as report a file with 0% coverage, even when using `--include-all-sources`. What gives? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instrument the code that is getting transpiled. Use this babel plugin: https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul

The package you're using `babel-istanbul` is a drop-in package meant to be used in replacement of babel.